# array showing nil when using in completion handler

Tags: objective-c, completionhandler

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]

startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"RESULT===%@",[[[result valueForKey:@"albums"] valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"id"]);

    arrayAlbum=[[[result valueForKey:@"albums"] valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"id"];
}];
```

my arrayAlbum showing nil for the first time how to rectify it??

Comment: Argh! My eyes!  Please format.

Comment: sorry i am new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Not enough information, how are you testing, what is the total result?

Comment: how to avoid delay getting values from completion handler??.result contains array of images from facebook

Comment: What does `NSLog` display when you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you allocated and initialised your array first?

arrayAlbum = [[NSArray alloc] init];